# Is there an AWS Cloud-formation equivalent on Linode?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, linode

What is the equivalent component of AWS CloudFormation Template in Linode ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The best way is probably through terraform which has [linode provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/linode/linode/latest/docs).